# "too many arguments for format" with macro

Tags: c, macros

I have a debug macro that I use for quick and dirty outputs.  I've been trying to determine how to make code compile clean on gcc 5.4.  It doesn't give any issues on earlier version of gcc (4.x) or clang (11.0.3).   The error is this:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:38: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
         do { if (1){ fprintf(stdout, "debug:%s:%04d:%s: " fmt, __FILE__, \
                                      ^
main.c:10:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEBUGPRINT’
  DEBUGPRINT("How to have no arguments?\n", NULL);
```

The code that I've been using to try to determine how to fix this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUGPRINT(fmt, ...) \
    do { if (1){ fprintf(stdout, "debug:%s:%04d:%s: " fmt, __FILE__, \
                            __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__);} } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DEBUGPRINT("nums: %04i, %04i\n", 0x1234,0x5678);
    DEBUGPRINT("How to have no arguments?\n", NULL);
    return(0);
}
```

As one can see, if I have arguments, there's not problem.  It's only if I have a message that's does not have arguments.  I guess that I could pass a "\n" with '%s', but I was just curious if there was a way to handle the NULL.

Comment: What purpose does the `if (1) { … }` serve in your macro definition?

Comment: @KonradRudolph When I gutted the code to make a simpler version, that is a legacy item.   It's due to the fact that there's different debug structures in the build, so that's usually a define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have no arguments, you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* SEPARATE THE COMMA FROM THE __VA_ARGS__ macro with
 * the ## token */
#define DEBUGPRINT(fmt, ...) \
    do { if (1){ fprintf(stdout, "debug:%s:%04d:%s: " fmt, __FILE__, \
                            __LINE__, __func__,## __VA_ARGS__);} } while (0)
/* THIS TOKEN ELIMINATES THE COMMA ------------^^  */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DEBUGPRINT("nums: %04i, %04i\n", 0x1234,0x5678);
    DEBUGPRINT("How to have no arguments?\n");
    return(0);
}
```

I'm afrid it is not included in the standard, but it is an extension shared by CLANG and GCC compilers.

This is the output on my system:

```
$ a.out
debug:pru3225.c:0012:main: nums: 4660, 22136
debug:pru3225.c:0013:main: How to have no arguments?
$ _
```

Answer (score 4):

The `fmt` argument needs to be left out, and you'll need to split the fixed part of the printing from the arguments you pass in.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUGPRINT(...) \
    do { printf("debug:%s:%04d:%s: ", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);\
         printf(__VA_ARGS__);\
    } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DEBUGPRINT("nums: %04i, %04i\n", 0x1234,0x5678);
    DEBUGPRINT("How to have no arguments?\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
debug:x1.c:0016:main: nums: 4660, 22136
debug:x1.c:0017:main: How to have no arguments?
```

Comment: It’s completely valid to paste two string literals as done by OP; your code doesn’t do what OP wants. The warnings looks spurious.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I forgot to remove `fmt` from the argument list.  Fixed.

Comment: Ugh, never mind, I misread GCC’s warning. Of course GCC is right. But your answer still doesn’t do what OP has in mind.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If no format arguments are passed there's a syntax error because `__VA_ARGS__` will be empty.  This addresses the issue.

Comment: It hardly addresses the issue, since *it changes the semantics*. That said, I don’t think there’s a solution in C (without compiler extensions), and there’s definitely no solution in C++ before C++20 (C++20 adds `__VA_OPT__` for this purpose).

Comment: `DEBUGPRINT("How to have no arguments yet with a %?\n")` will be a problem as `__VA_ARGS__` needs to be a valid   format string.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Exactly, it addresses the empty `__VA_ARGS__` issue and print the same as OP's code in other cases.  The only other thing I did was remove `if (1)` since it served no purpose.